# VelocityAutoConfiguration is deprecated in Spring Boot 1.4.*

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I upgraded Spring Boot dependency in my project and I realized that some classes, such as VelocityAutoConfiguration, are deprecated.

Do you know how can change this in Spring Boot 1.4.1?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = VelocityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Api {

@Value("${token.default}")
private String defaultToken;

@Value("${spring.server.secret.key}")
private String secretKey;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    new SpringApplication(Api.class).run(args);
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    AuthenticationFilter f = new AuthenticationFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(f);
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("defaultToken", defaultToken);
    registrationBean.addInitParameter("secretKey", secretKey);
    ArrayList<String> match = new ArrayList<>();
    registrationBean.setUrlPatterns(match);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
}
```

When I remove the line with VelocityAutoConfiguration.class I face with the problem below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: autovalue.shaded.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VelocityAutoConfiguration` is deprecated but still working. You cannot remove the line because without the line Spring Boot tries to configure Velocity.

You have to wait to version 1.5 if you want remove the line